# Horizontal CSS Layout

Tags: css, layout

I'm trying to learn to do things the "CSS" way as opposed to using tables. I have a basic form that needs to be layed out like the following:

```
Label 1: [Drop Down List]     Label 2: [Drop Down List]   Label 3: Drop Down List
```

Collectively, the three will be left aligned and NOT take up the entire width of the screen. However, the sizes of the drop down list elements will be dynamic based on the data that fills them. If I were using a table, I would just do the following:

```
<table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
  <tr>
    <td>Label 1:&nbsp;</td>
    <td style='padding-right:12px;'><select>...</select></td>

    <td>Label 2:&nbsp;</td>
    <td style='padding-right:12px;'><select>...</select></td>

    <td>Label 3:&nbsp;</td>
    <td style='padding-right:12px;'><select>...</select></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to do this via CSS. Any insights are appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just put all the elements after each other in the HTML and give the `label` elements `display:inline-block` and `margin-left: 50px`.

**HTML**

```
<label>Label 1 <select>...</select></label> 
<label>Label 2 <select>...</select></label> 
<label>Label 3 <select>...</select></label>
```

**CSS**

```
label {
 display: inline-block; /* perhaps not needed, as commented by cimmanon */
 margin-left: 50px;
}
```

**Live demo**
http://jsfiddle.net/Ezgtq/1/

Comment: Labels don't need to be set to `inline-block`, they're already inline by default: http://jsfiddle.net/Ezgtq/2/

Comment: `<label>` uses `for` attribute to specify that for which element it is for!

Comment: @cimmanon that's perhaps true, I must say I'm not sure. I just added the `inline-block` so the `margin-left` is applied (which doesnt work on inline elements). I do agree that a quick test without `inline-block` seems to prove that you are right.

Comment: @AspiringAqib the `for` attribute is not needed if the associated element is WITHIN the `label`.

Comment: I know But I wanna Ask You That When You Posted Answer, You had `display:block;` and after my answer was posted, it became `display:inline-block` ?

Comment: @Bazzz If you want to specify a width/height, then yes, it would need to be `inline-block`.

Comment: @AspiringAqib Yes I had `block` initially but that was a typo as I tried to be quick in answering the question. Later I corrected this to what I meant, namely `inline-block`. I don't see why that has relevance to your `for` attribute comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
Label: <select>....</select>
Label: <select>....</select>
Label: <select>....</select>
```

CSS:

```
select {
display:inline-block;
margin-left:12px;
width:40px; /* What You Want */
}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EdCPc/)